# How can I install boost multiprecision library in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I installed boost library in my ubuntu 12.04 machine using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

But when I checked `/usr/include/boost`, I don't see header files for multiprecision package (`cpp_dec_float.hpp`). Do I need to install it separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.Multiprecission is present in Boost 1.53 onwards.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/map/hist.html

If you install `libboost-all-dev` metapackage from `precise` repository by dependncy you get `libboost-dev` and by dependncy you also get `libboost1.46-dev` which is unfortunately too old.

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-all-dev
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-dev
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost1.46-dev

You might try your luck with some PPA repository.

E. g. this one:

https://launchpad.net/~apokluda/+archive/ubuntu/boost1.53

and install the package following this tutorial.

https://charmie11.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/install-boost-1-53-on-ubuntu-by-package-manager/